# How to change row group header in DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a hopefully simple problem. I want to change the information in a row group header of a DataGrid. 
The item source is a PagedDataCollection with a GroupDescription. I already changed the style like this:

```
<Controls:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
         <Style TargetType="Controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
          <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFB4DC69" />
          <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
          <Setter Property="SublevelIndent" Value="15" />
         </Style>

         <Style TargetType="Controls:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="#44225566" />
         </Style>
</Controls:ExtendedDataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
```

But hat only changed that the group name is not visible.
The group header looks like this now:
first header: Project 1 : (170 items)
second header: Project 2 : (10 items)
...

What I want to do now, is that the header looks like this:
Project 1 : 5 developer, 5 tester, 1 project manager
Project 2 : 1 developer, 1 tester, 1 project manager 
...

But I have no idea how this can be done.

Does anyone of you has done something similar and/or knows the answer to my problem.

Best regards,

TJ